# how form array in do-while?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to form array in the do-while:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE company='$companyID'", $db);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {       
            $resultData = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            do
            {           
                $json[] = array('product' => $resultData['product'], 'title' => $resultData['title']); 
            }       
            while($resultData = mysql_fetch_array($result));
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
```

In exit all datais empty(error):

```
"[{"product":"","title":""},{"product":"","title":""},{"product":"","title":""},{"product":"","title":""}]"
```

Comment: 1) Use a straight `while` instead of `do..while`, the latter just makes things more verbose here. 2) Perhaps you have the wrong fetch mode? Try `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `fetch_array`. 3) Strongly consider migrating away from the `mysql` extension -- it is old and has been deprecated.

Comment: 1. What do you expect? and why? From what I see, there are perfectly valid reasons for you getting the output that you get.
2. Put `var_export($resultData)` into the loop to see how the array is structured, that you get from the call to `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: try to get formed json :)

Comment: You get formed json :) Again, where is the problem?

Comment: @Oswald The problem is that all the values in the JSON are empty, probably due to Jon's point 2, which really should be an answer not a comment :)

Comment: @IMSoP No, that cannot be the problem, due to the default fetch mode being MYSQL_BOTH.

Comment: $resultData['product'] and $resultData['title'] not empty in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does it actually give you an error?

try printing out your output to see if you actually fetch anything from mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE company='".$companyID."'", $db);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {       

            while($resultData = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
              echo '<pre>';
              print_r($resultData);
              echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
```

if you do get output that way just replace the content between {} of while with             `echo json_encode($json);`

hope this helps.